# wfp charting toolkit: show data point values above all columns

Tags: wpf, charts

total emergency here. Just saw WPF for the first time and need this quick, so forgive me: if I don't provide enough info first time around I promise to edit the question.

In a charting object, defined with namespace:

```
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

I am drawing a simple bar chart.

```
<charting:Chart Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=MyCurrentResultsView, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=NullObjectToVisibilityConverter}}"
                       Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"
                       Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="350"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Title="{Binding Path=MyCurrentResultsView.Name}">
    <charting:ColumnSeries Height="350" Foreground="Black"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCurrentResultsView.ResultsView}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}">
    </charting:ColumnSeries>
</charting:Chart>
```

What I'd like to do is to show the value of each column above the column (or even inside the column rectangle if possible: these are percentage values and the idea is to make them more visible on the bar chart).

I have been looking at the styling information, but here this is more than just style. I see two possibilities. Either:

1. For each column item in the series, define a transformation that positions a frame above each column, creates a text box whose label is set to the dependent value, then draws the text box inside the frame.
2. Find some kind of property on "ColumnSeries" or "? ColumnItem ?" that "enables" the display of the bound value above the column.

Total shot in the dark here. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try to change the `ColumnDatapointTemplate` like this:

```
<charting:ColumnSeries Height="350" Foreground="Black"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCurrentResultsView.ResultsView}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}">
    <charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
                 <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Black"/>
                    <Grid Margin="0 -20 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" Margin="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                 </Grid>
                 </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </charting:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle> 
</charting:ColumnSeries>
```

Play a bit with vertical alignments and/or margins and you will be able to get infos into the columns and other.

Hope this help!

Comment: This is perfect! I found lots of doc pointing in different directions, but not the exact way to draw the label. This is exactly what I needed.